# Turning off the red underline for mispelled words in Libreoffice?

Tags: libreoffice

Firstly, I apologize, as this question has almost certainly been asked before. I just don't know the term for the red underline that appears under possibly misspelled words in the LibreOffice word editor, so I am unable to find any questions that would help me here.

I am taking notes for a class in Chinese history, and I'd like to know how to turn off these red underlines.

Since a lot of words and names are not in English it's annoying to see so many red underlines.

*How can I turn off the red underlining of misspelled words in LibreOffice?*

Comment: Try Tools - Automatic Spell Checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like mike suggested: from the tools menu deselect "automatic spell checking" (as a shortcut you can also press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks, I had assumed that meant _automatic spell correction_.